How to pre-process data correctly in order to retain positional information?
I am training a neural network for Direction of Arrival estimation. The CNN should learn the inverse mapping from the complex valued covariance matrix of array received data to the spatial
spectrum. In order to do so, the input to the CNN are the covariance matrix and the labels are 1 at the grid corresponding to the true directions, and otherwise 0. In order to do so I am using
mlb = MultiLabelBinarizer() #does a binary encoding yTrain_encoded =
yTrain_encoded = mlb.fit_transform(angles)

So if I have 4 angles say -50,56,64,13 yTrain_encoded will have 1 at indices 40,103,146,154 (because in a grid of -90 to 90, these are the indices that correspond to the given angle) and rest of the indices will have 0. So once the model is trained the output of the model will be have a high probability at these indices and if I map these indices with the grid of angles -90 to 90, I will get the angles. But in this process, the order in which the angles are arranged is not stored. In my case, I have prepared the dataset such that col1, col3 are the azimuth angles and col2,col4 are the elevation angles. But this information is completely lost in this way of encoding. Can anyone suggest some other of encoding if possible?
